# Unable to send data from html page to php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to work with youtube API and trying to send a link from html page to my php script.(I am actually creating an API). But when I click on submit, nothing happens !! even the page is not loaded

Here is my html page

```
<html>
<title>Youtube Video Information</title>
<body>
<h3>Paste  Video Url in the below box</h3>
<form name = "input" name = "input" action="youtubev3.php" method="GET">
<input type = "textarea" name = "videoURL" id = "videoURL"><br>
Comments: <input type = "checkbox" name = "comments"><br>
likes: <input type = "checkbox" name = "likes"><br>
dislikes: <input type = "checkbox" name = "dislikes"><br>
Views: <input type = "checkbox" name = "dislikes"><br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" name = "submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my php source code.

```
<?php

class youtubev3{
function __construct()
{
}
function getdata(){
  $string = $_POST['videoURL'];
  $urlID = trim($string,"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=");
  echo $urlID;
  $jsonObject = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$urlID}&key=AIzaSyDvM6lnjHv5YMBA6I7ROjv2yYbnohN4PNY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status");
  $json = json_decode($jsonObject);
  $comentCount = $json->{'kind'};
  //var_dump($json);
  //echo $videoType;
}
}
$getData1 = new youtubev3();
$getData1->getData();
// $videoType = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'kind'};
?>
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: look at your form method very carefully and the array for `$string`. I'd call that "undefined index..."

Comment: An `input` of `type=textarea`?

Comment: your form tag is having name attribute 2 times

Comment: 1. what is your controller?
2. check your firebug console... are you seeing any error under network? 
3. change to action="/youtubev3.php" method="POST"

Comment: your form won't be submitted as you have just a button not a button with type 'submit'

Comment: use button type 'submit' and check

Comment: In your form, you need a button with `type="submit"` not `type='button'`

Comment: Your form's method should be POST not GET: `method="POST"`

Comment: you dont need braces when accessing your object's method. Use this: `$json->kind;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your method is `GET` but you're looking for `$_POST`.
2. Your syntax is very messy. Ensure that each HTML tag - including `<form>`, `<input>` and `<button>` - has only one `name` attribute and `id` attribute.
3. To post the data, change the button type to `type="submit"` instead of `"button"`.
4. Use `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="textarea">` or, better yet for one-line inputs, use `<input type="text">`.

---

### Full, corrected code

```
<html>
    <title>Youtube Video Information</title>
    <body>
        <form action="youtubev3.php" id="input" method="post" name="input">
            <textarea id="videoURL" name="videoURL"></textarea><br>
            Comments: <input name="comments" type="checkbox"><br>
            likes: <input name="likes" type="checkbox"><br>
            dislikes: <input name="dislikes" type="checkbox"><br>
            Views: <input name="dislikes" type="checkbox"><br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: he is also using the name attribute two times

Comment: he also need to change his button type as submit instead of button

Comment: He has a lot of syntactical issues with his code, but even with perfect syntax, the script won't work unless the form method and retrieval method are the same.

Comment: a `textarea` is not even needed. For what he needs it seems that a normal `<input type="text" />` would suffice

Comment: That's not for us to judge... If he wants a textarea (as he's written), he's gone about it the wrong way. Whether or not he *needs* a textarea, well... Regardless, I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: well, if that's the case, then why are we judging the code at all?

Comment: Because he asked us to figure out why it isn't working - not how to improve the aesthetics! A `textarea`, while it may be unnecessary, would still work fine, and changing it won't affect the form's data.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file you are trying to get the URL in `$_POST` while from the form you are sending the data through get method.

Also the submit button has two name attributes.

```
<html>
<title>Youtube Video Information</title>
<body>
<h3>Paste  Video Url in the below box</h3>
<form name = "input" name = "input" action="youtubev3.php" method="POST">
<input type = "textarea" name = "videoURL" id = "videoURL"><br>
Comments: <input type = "checkbox" name = "comments"><br>
likes: <input type = "checkbox" name = "likes"><br>
dislikes: <input type = "checkbox" name = "dislikes"><br>
Views: <input type = "checkbox" name = "dislikes"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your html code. It contains lots of spacing and errors. Also the input type should be submit.